# How Can I plot scatter plot for each category in seperate graph

Tags: r, plot, scatter

I am fairly new to R and What I'd like to do is to scatter plot by category. I have a data set with 5 category (Item_nbr) and 19 variables. I want to have scatter plot for each category separately not in the same graph with different color. I mean generate 5 scatter plot. My data is :

```
Date         Units  avgdir  Item_nbr   tmax
1/1/2012       0     0.5      1         50
1/1/2012       2     0.2      2         40
1/1/2012       3     0.1      3         60
1/1/2012       10    0.7      4         70
1/1/2012        5    0.2      5         80
1/2/2012        6    0.8      1         90
1/2/2012        11   0.8      2         40
1/2/2012        12   0.8      3         70
1/2/2012        9    0.8      4         60
1/2/2012        8    0.8      5         70
............
```

Now How can I 5 scatter plot to plot units column in each of them.

Comment: what against what for each category? Do you mean like `Units` against `avgdir` for each category?

Comment: Unit against avgdir - and units against tmax

Comment: I have this error "Error in data[AllItems$item_nbr == i, ] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
for(i in unique(data$Item_nbr))
  plot(Units ~ avgdir, data[data$Item_nbr == i, ])
```

Comment: Thanks I run it but I have this error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" and It gave me one plot not 5 plot. If I have other columns (17 columns extra than avgdir) Can i use the same solution

Comment: Rename every data to your dsata.frame name (AllItems, i suppose?).